# Is there a way to specify the actual location of a file compiled with Pyinstaller (--onefile) and not the temporary _Meixxxx folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Recently I've been working on a Python project that requires human interaction with other files. I compiled it to one file. I tried to get the absolute path to that compiled file. However, everything the internet has suggested leads me to the _Meixxxx temp folder. Although useful, it's not very well situated for human interaction. Is there any way that I can find the absolute path to my exe file and not the _Meixxxx folder?

I've tried several things including:

```
os.cwdir
os.path.dirname
```

Thank you for any help in advance

EDIT:

Thanks to @johnashu

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

This seems to correctly find the path of the file location

Comment: `--distpath DIR`  Where to put the bundled app (default: ./dist)  -- https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html  -  set the path and you will know the location.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. However I want the exe to find itself even on a different computer

Comment: `dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

Comment: @johnashu Thanks will try, although doesn't seem promising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @johnashu suggested

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

should give you the actual location for your exe file